# Serve angular-cli from dist folder with nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, deployment, production-environment

I'm trying to serve my angular-cli application from the dist folder using nginx I used this command to generate dist

```
ng build --prod
```

then I moved the `dist` folder to my server and this is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name x.x.x.x;


    location /angular {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ angular/dist/index.html;
    }

}
```

now when I try to reach x.x.x.x/angular I got 404 Not Found

Whats wrong with my configuration?

Comment: try: "location /angular/ {}" And are you maintaining logs? can you post ngnix logs here?

Answer (score 4):

- Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.
- You have to use the following command to build:

  `ng build --prod --base-href http://x.x.x.x`
- Now check your nginx server configuration and restart nginx.

  ```
  server {

      listen 80;

      server_name http://x.x.x.x;

      root /path/to/your/dist/location;

      index index.html index.htm;

      location / {

          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

          # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

      }

  }
  ```

For more information check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612339/how-can-i-deploy-my-angular-2-typescript-webpack-app/49505211#49462818).

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: This helped me get rid of the 404 page when reload Angular App. Thanks!