# Load static files using nginx for .net core app

Tags: nginx, .net-core, reverse-proxy, static-files

I use Angular + .NET Core application and decided to get rid of IIS as a reverse proxy server. In the first step I decide to run nginx locally. I have app1 and app2. By default nginx run app1 and if user is not authenticated it redirects to app2. For app2 I use Razor Pages and all is working fine. For app1 I use Angular and made a production build to /wwwroot/dist folder. I encountered with failed loading static files (.js, .css) because it tries to get from wrong location.(It always goes to *localhost/*.css* instead of *localhost/wwroot/dist/*.css*)

How can I override static file directory?

**nginx conf**

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8187;
        server_name  localhost;
        
        location /static/ {
            alias /wwwroot/dist/;
            expires 7d;  # Optionally, set caching for static files
        }
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8201;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
        
        location /login {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8202;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Also instead of location /static I tried, but it didn't help.

```
location ~* /(css|js|lib) {
        root /var/www/demo/wwwroot;
    }
```

How could I fix that issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serve angular-cli from dist folder with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056423/serve-angular-cli-from-dist-folder-with-nginx)

Comment: I am not sure. I have 500 error while question which you provided about 404 error. I am not able to set correct path for static files

Comment: Have you tried switching `alias /wwwroot/dist/` for `root /wwwroot/dist/`? Using root will append `static` to the search directory, which I think may solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. It still goes to localhost/style.css instead of  localhost/wwwroot/dist/style.css