# Deploying Angular2 app in Nginx in Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

Can anyone please explain the steps or provide a link that I can look into to demonstrate how to deploy my Angular2 app in a Nginx server.? My current position is, my Angular2 2 app is running on Angular2 CLI server and back end is NodeJs running on Express server.                                                Please do explain from how to install Nginx to deploy in production as I am new to the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deploy my Angular 2 + Typescript + Webpack app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612339/how-can-i-deploy-my-angular-2-typescript-webpack-app)

Comment: @WildanS.Nahar In the link that you gave, its in the Linux environment, moreover I am not understanding the steps to edit the server config. In short, I have the dist folder ready, but not sure how to install and deploy in windows. Edited my question as well.

Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, providing tutorial on nginx installation in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the links that show deploying angular 2 app on nginx :

[Angular 2 Official Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612339/how-can-i-deploy-my-angular-2-typescript-webpack-app)

[From blog](http://brandonbohling.com/technology/ng-nginx-pm2/)

For Windows, please follow these instructions to install Nginx in Windows :

[Nginx official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)

[Blog tutorial](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/nginx-windows-how-to-install/)

After that, the rest step is just the same as the other environment, so you only have to dive deeper with nginx.

Hope this helps