# Deploy single page application Angular: 404 Not Found nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application, angular-routing, cloud-foundry

I Have an Angular application. I run the command `ng build --prod --aot` to generate the **dist** folder.
In the dist folder I created a file named **Staticfile** then I uploaded the dist folder to [pivotal.io](https://pivotal.io/) with the following commands:

1. cf push name-app --no-start
2. cf start name-app

The app runs well. I have a nav bar, so when I change the path with navbar everything works fine. But when I do it manually (I enter the url myself) I have this error **404 Not Found nginx**.
This my app.component.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'time-picker', component: TimePickerComponent },
  { path: 'material-picker', component: MaterialPickerComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/time-picker',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TimePickerComponent,
    MaterialPickerComponent,
    DurationCardComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes
    // ,{ enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
  ),
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MdCardModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdInputModule

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr-br');
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833154 to update your nginx config file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found the answer:
After I generated the **dist** folder.

- I created a file called **Staticfile** and put it in the dist folder
- I opened **Staticfile** & I added this line `pushstate: enabled`

pushstate enabled keeps browser-visible URLs clean for client-side JavaScript apps that serve multiple routes. For example, pushstate routing allows a single JavaScript file route to multiple anchor-tagged URLs that look like /some/path1 instead of /some#path1.

Comment: I am running into exact same issue but this didn't work me, any idea what could I be missing?am on angular8

Answer (score 98):

for those not using a **Staticfile**  might wanna try this.

I had the same problem with nginx serving angular.
The following is the default config file, probably found somewhere in /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite

```
     location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

but what we acctually want is...

```
     location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

Comment: Yes you're right. This method works too. But in my case I was using PWS which is a PaaS, so it couldn't work. +1 though for it could help people in the future

Comment: Hi I'm really confused on how to actually get to /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite    for my react app. Please help.

Comment: @John, this path is where nginx configuration would be found if you are on Unix-based OS, and ofc are using nginx., is this the case for you?

Comment: I'm on a windows machine @Sven. How do I get to the location? Any ideas?

Comment: @John read up on http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: You saved me with the `/` at the beginning of `/index.html`

Comment: You saved my evening! I can now go to bed and hug my wife and boy!

Comment: It's work if I added location/ui/health is health check ?

Answer (score 43):

In your `nginx.conf` file try using:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

instead of:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

That worked for me on Angular 5 project.

Comment: this exactly what @Marko Letic said. What is the difference in this answer?

Comment: If anyone is trying this solution and did not work. Check your nginx.conf if you did not miss adding root /dist of your index.html file. This is what happens to me forgot to add root /pathofmydist

Comment: Normally, the configuration is in `sites-avaiable/yourdomain`

Answer (score 9):

I assume your all data of `/dist` directory is now in `/var/www/your-domain/`, if not then first paste on that

now your url is only accepted homepage or landing page otherwise they show 404 error.

In this condition find your ngnix's `/default` file, In Linux path like that `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, In this file, you will see like that

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404
```

replace with

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

now you restart your ngnix server with command in linux

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

and see status of ngnix with

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with the server side not the Angular side of things . It is the servers responsibility to return the index or the landing page for each request in your case `nginx`.

**UPDATE**

If you by any means do not have a backend or server where you can configure this there are two workarounds.

- Using `HashLocationStrategy` in Angular
- Making some tweak in index.html file [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) No -15

Comment: i have a workaround for this problem if you donot want to go via the nginx config way but mind it is a strict work around [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) check the question 15 [last one]

Comment: I already told you Sir that all I did was creating an Angular application. I have done no work in the back end

Comment: this is a work around for the frontend only , please check the link in the comment sir . you need to make that change in your index.html. I will update in the answer too

Comment: @Melchia hope you get it now

Comment: I don't understand, I visited your website nothing is there

Comment: I went here https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/home#collapse15

Comment: @Melchia that is solution i was talking about it works on ghpages as well as for this scenarios. I hope

Comment: No the problem you'talking about is different. I don't have this error when I refresh my page , I get this error only when I manually enter the URL

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a permission issue, Nginx has to be the owner of the directory where you put your dist, i've seen this error in the nginx log file

```
"root/../../dist/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

so i gave permissions to nginx user on the top folder containing my dist

```
chown nginx . -R //  to give nginx the permissions on the current directory, and everything in it.
```

and then you have to restart nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

and it should work!

Comment: After everything was failing for me, I saw your answer way down here and realized I had to restart nginx

Answer (score 1):

Angular applications are single page applications. When you type the address manually you try to route to a location where the application is not running.

You need to edit nginx config to route to your base page.

Comment: I don't have nginx config, the only steps I did are the ones I wrote above. I just added a Staticfile and then pushed the dist folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612339/how-can-i-deploy-my-angular-2-typescript-webpack-app

Comment: How to config nginx for pivotal.io. I don't have a server side all I did was in Front end side.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an nginx configuration issue following this required to overcome this issue.

In your nginx.conf file try using:

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

instead of:

> try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

Then afterward also to need change the following.

from:

```
 error_page 404 index.html;
```

To

```
error_page 404 /actualPathToDistFolder/index.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are deploying your angular app to `S3` you need to set up your `Error Document` and index Document to `index.html` and empty redirection rules (/properties/static website)
[image: S3 Angular deployment setting under path s3/properties/static website]