# 404 Not Found for redirecting home page on nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, redirect, routes, http-status-code-404

I am trying to deploy my Angular-NodeJS project on a server, I used nginx for Angular part and PM2 for NodeJs part. When I try the server address http://95.216.132.229/ it works fine and redirects to the http://95.216.132.229/home, but when I refresh the page it gives `404 Not Found` error! I haven't this problem when I try to run my project locally.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: keep this   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true})] in app-routing.module.ts

Comment: You have to configure nginx to redirect all Urls to the index.html, so angular can handle the routes. Check out this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858957/deploy-single-page-application-angular-404-not-found-nginx.).